What is the correct syntax for specifying length for positive look behind?
I have a series of expressions that start with numbers of different length and I would like to extract the string after these numbers: e.g. c("14ac", "148me3") I would like to get c("ac", "me3).
I wrote this expression
xx <- c("14ac", "148me3")
str_extract(xx, "(?<=\\d+).*")

but it doesn't work because in stringr you need a limit on look behind length. I get the error:
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length. (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT, context=(?<=\d+).*)
Then I tried
xx <- c("14ac", "148me3")
str_extract(xx, "(?<=\\d{1, 10}).*")

but this also doesn't work
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL, context=(?<=\d{1, 10}).*)
could anyone please let me know what is the correct way to write this?

Try with something like str_replace(xx, pattern = "^\\d{1,10}(.*)", replacement = "\\1")

Look-behinds should be of fixed length, so '(?<=\\d+)' or '(?<=\\d{1, n})' are invalid. Instead capture the first characters,
> stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(xx, '[a-z].*')
[1] "ac"   "me3"  "mmm1"

or delete leading digits.
> sub('^\\d+', '', xx)
[1] "ac"   "me3"  "mmm1"

> stringi::stri_replace_first_regex(xx, '^\\d+', '')
[1] "ac"   "me3"  "mmm1"


Data:
c("14ac", "148me3", "mmm1")


stringr::str_split_fixed(string = xx,pattern = "\\d*",n=2)[,2]
# [1] "ac"  "me3"

or simplifying Ric's comment suggestion to the minimum:
stringr::str_replace(xx, pattern = "^\\d*", replacement = "")
# [1] "ac"  "me3"

